# sql query for all values in single row

Tags: sql

This is my existing table

```
ID  Patient Study   AVA LVOT    LV  AVPG
AA11 11 3   0   12  0   0
AA11 11 3   0   0   123 0
AA11 11 3   0   0   0   456
AA11 11 3   902 0   0   0
AA12 12     4       0       0       10      0
AA12 12     4       90      0       0       0
AA12 12     4       0       34      0       0
AA12 12     4       0       0       0       18
```

and this is my required output  all values in single row how this can be done

```
ID  Patient Study   AVA LVOT    LV  AVPG
AA11    11  3   902 12  123 456
AA12    12  3   90  34  10  18
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by adding what you've tried to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: I need all values in single row you see duplicate rows AA11 four times. It should be single row AA11   11    3  902   12    123    456

Comment: Can you show your unsuccessful attempt?

Comment: I have a very long query which is producing multiple rows..

Comment: So long that is not fit in SO?

Comment: here I am showing only one ID  AA11   there are many records like this..

Comment: You must show your query not the source data.

Comment: You can use group by and aggregate functions to get the result you want but that is most likely not how you should fixe your very long query. It looks like you need to have a look at how you join the tables in your query.

Comment: Why in the existing table there is only one value beside the ID/Patient/Study? Then again a group on those three column and a max in everything else is enought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your values are positive, this should do what you want:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Patient, t.Study,
       SUM(t.AVA) as AVA, SUM(t.LVOT) as LVOT, SUM(t.LV) as LV, SUM(t.AVPG) as AVPG
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.ID, t.Patient, t.Study;
```

You don't mention the specific database you are using, but this is standard SQL and should work in any database.